# Counting and logic is kicking my behind I

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

I have the following question as homework, and I am still clueless as to how to approach these problems. Just when I think I have a hand of how to solve card related problems, I get thrown another that just leaves me clueless. Any who, I would appreciate any help afforded in explaining the problem below

**How many strictly increasing sequences of integers are there that begin with $1$ and end with $n$, where $n>1$? For example, if $n =4$, there are $4$ such sequences: $1,4;\quad  1,2,4;\quad 1,3,4;\quad 1,2,3,4$ . Prove your answer with strong induction**

Comment: Have you tried a few small cases and found a pattern?  This should be your first move.

Comment: Yes, but that has not yielded an idea to solve this yet.

Comment: Large Hint: First make a **very careful** list of the possibilities for $n=2$; $n=3$; $n=4$; $n=5$. The counts should be $1$, $2$, $4$, $8$ respectively.  Now let's deal with $n=6$.  Any good sequence for $6$ has one of the following shapes: (i) **Any** one of the earlier sequences, followed by a $6$ or (ii) a bare $6$. So how many sequences are there for $n=6$ (count them *without* listing).  By the way, there are better ways to do the job, **without** using strong induction!

Comment: HINT Any such sequence has a $1$ in the beginning and an $n$ at the end. The middle elements (those strictly between $1$ and $n$) may or may not be present. But if I told you which of the middle elements are present in the sequence, can you write down the sequence uniquely?

Comment: @André Careful, you cannot have a bare $6$ since the sequence must start with $1$. (The idea works fine though once you take care of this.)

Comment: @Srivatsan Narayanan: Thanks, by a bare $6$ I *meant* $(1,6)$. But that's definitely not what I *wrote*.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: +1 for mentioning that there are better ways to do this than strong induction.

Comment: @Hans Parshall: I thought however that I should give the strong induction idea, since it is probably what the instructor/book had in mind.

Comment: In MSE the title of a question should focus the *contents* of a problem rather than your comment, your opinion or your feeling about it. Please stay in tune with that behave.

Answer (score 2):

Let's call strictly increasing sequences beginning with 1 and ending with $n$ "good"; let $s(n)$ be the number of good sequences for $n$.

Note there is only one good sequence for each $n$ with no terms between $1$ and $n$.  Consider all good sequences with middle terms.

If we have a good sequence $1, a_1, \ldots, a_k, n$, how many choices do we have for $a_k$?  We could have $a_k = 2$, $a_k = 3$, $\ldots$, or $a_k = n - 1$.

How many good sequences could we possibly have for each $a_k$?  Observe this is completely determined by the increasing sequence $1, a_1, \ldots, a_k$, which is a good sequence (for $a_k$ rather than $n$).  This is counted by $s(a_k)$. If you have an inductive hypothesis for the values of $s(2), \ldots, s(n-1)$, then you have a value (in terms of $a_k$) for each $s(a_k)$.  Add each of these up for each possible value of $a_k$, and this will be very close to $s(n)$.

I'll leave it to you to find the pattern so you have a value for each $a_k$ in your inductive hypothesis.

Answer (score 2):

These sequences are in $1$-$1$ correspondence with the subsets of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ containing $1$ and $n$. There are $2^{n-2}$ such subsets.

Answer (score 0):

That's just binary counting no ?
You always have $1$ and $n$ in you sequence. Let's focus on digits $2$ to $n-1$.
Write it in a tabluar : you have $n-2$ columns entiteled $(n-1)$, $(n-2)$, $\ldots$, $4$,  $3$,  $2$.
write a $1$ in a column if the digit is in the sequence, and $0$ if not... and count the number of lines corresponding to your constraint "strictly inclreasing" (don't forget the first one corresponding to sequence "1-n", i.e. 0 everywhere in cols $2$ to $(n-1)$).
Don't you see anything ? (for example that you have $2^{(n-2)}$ possibilities ?)

Comment: @Norbert: I don't really see the need to bump a 10-month-old question to the front page just to add some LaTeX tags.

Comment: @RahulNarain, I just edit questions which proposed on the review page as bad formatted.